# How do you save an Excel document as a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, file-format

I was hoping someone could tell me how to save a Microsoft Office Excel document to the Microsoft Office Word document format?

Comment: You know they're completely different document types right?

Comment: Do you mean how to embed it?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is cut/copy-and-paste each page from the Excel workbook into the Word document, and then save it in Word.

Comment: No need for cut-and-paste , copy-and-paste will also work

Comment: @Wishwas, thanks for bringing that to my attention, edited.

Answer (score -1):

I hope there is a better way than this but I think this trumps copy and paste.  Save it as a PDF then save the pdf as word.  still hoping for a better solution but it seems microsoft didn't consider switching among its own formats

Comment: The trouble with that would be that you lose formulas and relationships between cells, which are one of the main purposes of a spreadsheet.

Comment: @cpast You'd lose all this if you convert any XLS to DOC anyways.

Answer (score -2):

A possible way is...open word and select INSERT...then SELECT TABLE...search for excel document.

Comment: This is just embedding, not saving as...